# How do you sort a list by an element inside the object the list uses?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am working on a piece of coursework and part of this involves me having to have a working scoreboard in my game, however, I need a way to sort my list of the Score object by score.score. As my Score object contains the players name and also the level they reached.

I am not very experienced in programming and have been doing it for less than a year, all I've found from searching is people talking about lambda or IComparable, both of which I don't know anything about or how to use and MSDN doesn't seem to make it easy to understand for me :(

I'm pulling my hair out here, any help would be great!

In pseudo all I need is:

```
List<Score> scores;
// Load in scores
scores.Sort(//sort by score.actualScore)
```

So that I can add to and remove from the list in the correct places when a new score is added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ordered = scores.OrderBy(x => x.ActualScore).ToList();
```

Or:

```
var ordered = scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.ActualScore).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to pass it a [`Comparison` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx). For your example, that would be:

```
scores.Sort((a, b) => a.actualScore - b.actualScore);
```

Comment: Or more generally, myList.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)), assuming the type of myList implements IComparable<T>.

Comment: @Dr_Asik: If `T : IComparable<T>`, then won't `Sort` use it automatically and render the `Comparison` unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, I meant: myList.Sort((a, b) => a.Property1.CompareTo(b.Property1));

Answer (score 1):

Implement `IComparable` in your `Score` class.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx